# How do I make operator not case-sensitive on column names?

Tags: azure, kql

I'm trying to `project` a column, but the column headings don't have a consistent casing. How can I merge these into a single column? I tried using `tolower` in several places,

(example)

`tolower(parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody))).Properties.PrincipalType`

But receiving an error like

`Path expression Properties_PrincipalType source must be scalar of type 'dynamic'. Received a source of type string instead`.

Also, I'm not sure that a line like this is the most optimal way to project the column?
`parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)).Properties.PrincipalType`

**Sample**

```
datatable(OperationName:string, Properties:dynamic)
[
    "Create role assignment", dynamic( {"requestbody":"{\"Id\":\"6c646e88-b034-4486-8e77-b62b2aaffd75\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"b38e5be0-fff5-4de3-8a89-069ab41495d1\",\"PrincipalType\":\"Group\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/f94d2a34-3e3c-4a04-acab-beaffc4d55ed\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/0a21e950-3eea-45cc-9424-c412d1c89c5f/resourceGroups/rg-01\",\"Condition\":null,\"ConditionVersion\":null}}","eventCategory":"Administrative","entity":"/subscriptions/fd78615b-5c34-4858-a974-c7342e5aa0e5/resourceGroups/rg-01/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/d7408255-6c7c-4bec-8c4d-bb589d5bb92c","message":"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write","hierarchy":"3f8525ff-c00d-459b-8c75-28ecc60c70d4/Subscription01/f848451c-bc59-4fa8-84db-02ab33ff2aa8"} ),
    "Create role assignment", dynamic( {"requestbody":"{\"properties\":{\"roleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/9acda363-2bb6-4482-82be-5d9792bf3927/resourceGroups/rg-02/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b48dfeca-c01b-4b03-8e3e-8a8d21ae027d\",\"principalId\":\"8fb360df-a2ce-4cab-810f-e68a95876032\",\"principalType\":\"Group\"}}","eventCategory":"Administrative","entity":"/subscriptions/afc975b2-97f3-4717-a20e-7d53b60cbd08/resourceGroups/rg-02/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/ab8bbf8f-2336-483e-b49f-ed6815ca303b","message":"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write","hierarchy":"3ba18132-011f-4707-bf07-e5c9d8ad520e/Subscription01/fac4b1ec-2224-45ca-a30d-75e5eea5046c"} )
]
| project OperationName, 
    PrincipalType1 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)).Properties.PrincipalType, 
    PrincipalType2 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)).properties.principalType, 
    PrincipalId1 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)).Properties.PrincipalId, 
    PrincipalId2 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)).properties.principalId
```

**Result**

| OperationName | PrincipalType1 | PrincipalType2 | PrincipalId1 | PrincipalId2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Create role assignment | Group |  | b38e5be0-fff5-4de3-8a89-069ab41495d1 |  |
| Create role assignment |  | Group |  | 8fb360df-a2ce-4cab-810f-e68a95876032 |

**Desired result**

| OperationName | PrincipalType | PrincipalId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Create role assignment | Group | b38e5be0-fff5-4de3-8a89-069ab41495d1 |
| Create role assignment | Group | 8fb360df-a2ce-4cab-810f-e68a95876032 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there are only 2 casing options that are known in advance (e.g. lowercase `p` and uppercase `P`) - you can use the [`coalesce()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction).

for example:

```
datatable(OperationName: string, Properties: dynamic)
[
    "Create role assignment", dynamic({"requestbody": "{\"Id\":\"6c646e88-b034-4486-8e77-b62b2aaffd75\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"b38e5be0-fff5-4de3-8a89-069ab41495d1\",\"PrincipalType\":\"Group\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/f94d2a34-3e3c-4a04-acab-beaffc4d55ed\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/0a21e950-3eea-45cc-9424-c412d1c89c5f/resourceGroups/rg-01\",\"Condition\":null,\"ConditionVersion\":null}}", "eventCategory": "Administrative", "entity": "/subscriptions/fd78615b-5c34-4858-a974-c7342e5aa0e5/resourceGroups/rg-01/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/d7408255-6c7c-4bec-8c4d-bb589d5bb92c", "message": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write", "hierarchy": "3f8525ff-c00d-459b-8c75-28ecc60c70d4/Subscription01/f848451c-bc59-4fa8-84db-02ab33ff2aa8"}),
    "Create role assignment", dynamic({"requestbody": "{\"properties\":{\"roleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/9acda363-2bb6-4482-82be-5d9792bf3927/resourceGroups/rg-02/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b48dfeca-c01b-4b03-8e3e-8a8d21ae027d\",\"principalId\":\"8fb360df-a2ce-4cab-810f-e68a95876032\",\"principalType\":\"Group\"}}", "eventCategory": "Administrative", "entity": "/subscriptions/afc975b2-97f3-4717-a20e-7d53b60cbd08/resourceGroups/rg-02/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/ab8bbf8f-2336-483e-b49f-ed6815ca303b", "message": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write", "hierarchy": "3ba18132-011f-4707-bf07-e5c9d8ad520e/Subscription01/fac4b1ec-2224-45ca-a30d-75e5eea5046c"})
]
| extend requestBody = parse_json(tostring(Properties.requestbody))
| project
    OperationName, 
    PrincipalType = coalesce(requestBody.Properties.PrincipalType,
                             requestBody.properties.principalType),
    PrincipalId = coalesce(requestBody.Properties.PrincipalId, 
                           requestBody.properties.principalId)
```

| OperationName | PrincipalType | PrincipalId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Create role assignment | Group | b38e5be0-fff5-4de3-8a89-069ab41495d1 |
| Create role assignment | Group | 8fb360df-a2ce-4cab-810f-e68a95876032 |

Comment: Great thank you, any additional option if all the case options are unknown?

Comment: ideally, you should fix the client code that generates the data with unpredictable casing

Comment: This is directly from Microsoft :/

Comment: if you mean that an application developed by Microsoft is emitting records with wrong casing, then I would recommend opening a support ticket / feature request for the application you're using.

Comment: for what it's worth, i opened a case with MS and we determined that each resource provider (Azure portal, PowerShell, Azure Resource Manager, etc.) were all using their own casing in their API calls, and it wouldn't be feasible to enforce a standardized casing for all the providers